# Math returns wrong answers

Tags: php, math

I've been trying to get this work for almost an hour now, and it's constantly eluding me.

```
public static function npcBattleStats($npc) {
    $npc = self::findNPC($npc);
    $rand = mt_rand(1.2, 3.3);
    $npcStats['attack'] = (($npc['level'] * $npc['power']) / $rand);
    $npcSpeeda = round($npc['power'] / 2.4);
    $npcSpeedb = round(($npc['power'] / 1.1) + 2);
    $npcStats['speed'] = mt_rand($npcSpeeda, $npcSpeedb);
    return $npcStats;
}

level = 3 | power = 50
$npcStats['attack'] = (($npc['level'] * $npc['power']) / $rand);
```

Everything else seems to work properly, but the attack is constantly off. It should be between 45 and 115 but only returns the following.

```
[attack] => 50 | [attack] => 150 | [attack] => 75
```

I hope I'm not missing something simple here, but help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First mistake: `mt_rand` expects and returns integers.  So you're basically asking for and getting an int between 1 and 3, inclusive.

Comment: @cHao - Unfortunately rand() seems to work the same way. Would there be a better method of obtaining a random number between them?

Comment: ^ Try using `$rand = mt_rand(1.2*10, 3.3*10)/10;`

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how 150 / (1.3 -> 3.3) should return something between 15 and 42. 150/3.3 = 45.45 rep -- so the minimum range here is 45.45 -> 115.38

Comment: @RUJordan - Was an error in my math for those values. I was originally only dividing by 50 on the calculator. I edited my post accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Funktion mt_rand() only spits aut integers, not floats. Try this instead:

```
$rand = mt_rand(12, 33) / 10;
```

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't realized that it only worked with ints. This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

First of all as cHao mentioned
PHP manual: "Return value: A random **integer** value between min (or 0) and max (or mt_getrandmax(), inclusive), or FALSE if max is less than min."

To get it fixed you need something like this

```
$rand = mt_rand(35, 100) / 10;
//35 is your max
//120 is your low
```

So when You get:
your max:

```
(5 * 50) / 3.5 = 42.85.. //so round it
```

your low:

```
(5 * 50) / 10 = 15
```